Why do "hybrid" demons have so much success?
My brothers and I like to joke that being a "hybrid" demon (those that are demons but know a breathing style) is basically a free pass to the upper moons, which isn't necessarily untrue considering both of these types were upper moons (Kokoshibo and Kaigaku). But why exactly are these demons favored?

It's simple: they are exceptionally strong and have insane powers. For example, Kokushibo uses an insanely strong breathing style named "Moon breathing", derived from his brother Yoriichi's original Sun breathing. Generally, demons who practice breathing styles are extremely strong, since they have both their usual blood demon art, regeneration abilities, and Hashira-level breathing techniques. Thus, they probably are favored by Muzan due to their strength.
